# Apollo client 3 evict object from cache

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Using apollo client 3. Queried all countries and want to remove one country from cache and re-render UI.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/selectable-apollo-linlk-duycv?file=/src/App.tsx:1301-1445)

Tried like below;

```
onClick={() => {
 cache.evict({ id: `Country:${country.code}` });
 cache.gc();
}}
```

But didn't work. How to evict a country?

Answer (score 10):

Eviction should be used this way;

```
onClick={() => {
   cache.evict({ id: cache.identify(country) });
   cache.gc();
}}
```

Now the country removed and page rerendered. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/selectable-apollo-linlk-duycv?file=/src/App.tsx:1302-1443) updated

Comment: I get `TypeError: cache.identify is not a function` in the console?

Comment: when hover over cache, it should be infered as `InMemoryCache`.